# Connecting to Impala DB using Dask Library

Tags: connection-string, dask, impala, cloudera-cdp

I am trying to connect to Impala DB through Dask Library to fetch all data from a table using the read_sql_table(). Need the connection string to connect to, I have tried using the connection string that I generally connect in Dbeaver but it fails saying that not able to load the plugin: 'impala'.

Can someone help me connect to the Impala DB using Dask library or let me know if Dask supports Impala connection? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dask's `read_sql_table` uses the pandas version of it to fetch single chunks of data. So if your URI (connection string) works with pandas, it should also work with dask.
I found [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/impala-python-pandas.rst) tutorial which tells me, that the URI for impala should probably look like this `apacheimpala:///?Server=127.0.0.1&Port=21050`
I could not verify anything of this, because you have not posted a minimal working example and I don't have any impala DB flying around.